# Duplicate entries when adding new entries to DB with entity framework triggered via React GUI

Tags: asp.net, database, reactjs, entity-framework, code-first

I inherited an existing project in ASP.net/C# using the entity framework with code-first approach. I defined a new table and successfully did all the migration necessary so that the `[myProject].[ExportFiles]` is indeed visible as table in the database.

The following code works fine, except that it always creates double database entries. I am sure that the code is only called once, I checked that using breakpoints. Assume that my datbase context is called `_db`.

```
namespace myProject.Service
   {
      public void Export(int userId)
         {
            var currentExportTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
            var currentUserId = 42;
            var exportRecord= new ExportFiles // defining a new entry
               {
                  FileName = cashflowFileName,
                  DateSubmitted = currentExportTimestamp,
                  UserId = currentUserId,
               };
           _db.ExportFiles.Add(exportRecord); // nothing written in DB yet
           _db.SaveChanges(); // the entry is written to DB, but twice
         };
   };
```

The curious thing: **The code above always writes two new records with increasing `Id`s**, although it has only has a single reference, the `ExportController.cs` looks roughly as follows:

```
[Route("api/Export", Order = -1)]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Export(int? selectedEntityId, DateTime? selectedDate)
   {
      var name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
      var userId = _userService.GetUserByName(name).Id;

      if (selectedDate == null || selectedEntityId == null)
         {
            return BadRequest("Need to select appropriate data");
         }
      try
         {
            _export.Export(userId);
            return Ok();
         }
   }
```

My debugging exercise revealed that this controller is already called twice, but I am not sure why.

The component `MyView.tsx` looks as follows:

```
export interface MyViewProps {
    selectedDate: any,
    selectedEntity: number,
    exportStatus: boolean
    setExportingStatus: (exportingStatus: boolean) => void;
    selectDate: (date: any) => void;
    selectEntity: (entityId: number) => void;
    exportDispatch: () => void;
}

export class MyView extends React.Component<MyViewProps, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleExport = this.handleExport.bind(this);
    }
    handleExport() {
        this.props.setExportingStatus(true); 
        this.props.exportDispatch();
    }

    render() {  
        return (
            <div>
                <Button
                    type="primary"
                    onClick={this.handleExport}
                    disabled={this.props.exportStatus == true}
                    > Export
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

#### Additional information needed

The data model reads:

```
namespace myProject.Entity.Models
{
    public class ExportFiles
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `currentUserId = 42` does exist as foreign key in the table `User`.

#### Edit

I figured that that the function is actually called twice, but I do not understand why.

#### Related questions

- [Entity Framework Creates New / Duplicate Entries for Associated Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710178/)

Comment: Are the DateSubmitted value equals on both records? so that we can eliminate the scenario where you are calling the method twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code it's correct, checking whether the DateSubmitted value is the same in both of your duplicate values will tell you if indeed your record it's being duplicated by the `.SaveChanges()` method or if you are just calling the entire method twice.

Edit: Since you added the React Code i can see that you are registering to the event without needing it since you already are triggering it with the button click so this `this.handleExport = this.handleExport.bind(this);` is creating the duplicate requests

```
export class MyView extends React.Component<MyViewProps, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    handleExport() {
        this.props.setExportingStatus(true); 
        this.props.exportDispatch();
    }

    render() {  
        return (
            <div>
                <Button
                    type="primary"
                    onClick={this.handleExport}
                    disabled={this.props.exportStatus == true}
                    > Export
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```